# How to compile code online?

Tags: php, compiler-construction

How can you build a site like http://ideone.com/  which will compile/run like 40 different languages?  I don't need 40 language support but would like to be able to run PHP and possibly a couple others on a personal pastebin project, any help appreciated on how to accomplish this

Comment: Before that, are you aware of the security issues related with what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Get user input, write into a temp file, point the compiler or whatever at it, capture the output and display it. You 've probably done all of this at some point or other.

Comment: I'm with Yoda here. If you need help designing such a service, you should probably not start the endeavor

Comment: My guess is that the site is being hosted on a dedicated *nix box with input being piped via command line to compilers.

Comment: People, allow the OP some opportunity to learn. He hasn't said he intends to make a public service out of it.

Comment: @Jon - While I agree with the basic premise of your question, I would say that for such a task a developer would need to know what they are doing. As a project on a local machine it may be a good tool, but in the wild, even behind a firewall within a VPN, it could cause some real problems if not completed in an expert fashion. This seems ripe for extended tutorial/book territory, which seems a bit long for an SO question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Did you learn how to protect against SQL injections before writing your first database-driven program or after?

Comment: @Jon - This is a question and answer site. This is a question that is complex in such as a way as I believe it should be done in smaller blocks, not one big block. Hence, my comment. I don't know the answer, but I know it would be a stepwise approach and for a live system I would have to monitor and patch often. For someone new to most of the concepts, I would suggest finding a comprehensive, expert source, not a Q/A site.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I fully agree that the question should be broken down, and this is why I did not answer myself and only left a comment. Perhaps after it is closed the OP will ask for specific help on some of the steps if they feel the need, and *those* questions will hopefully be a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Jon - Agreed. I also upvoted your comment a while back, since I share the sentiment, but I felt the need to express my specific thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For compiled languages, you would have to write something to invoke a [probably command-line] compiler sitting on the web-server, feeding it the user input source. For PHP, you can execute code using `eval()`, but it's probably safer (and certainly more portable) to invoke the PHP interpreter instead.

Of course, executing arbitrary user-input source code **poses serious security risks**, so I imagine http://ideone.com/ executes the resulting binaries in some sort of sandbox.

I wouldn't recommend using `eval()` on user input unless you have configured your web server to severely restrict PHP, and have some sort of third-party library (don't reinvent the wheel) for identifying malicious code.

Comment: `eval()` runs a string of PHP code. `exec()` is for executing utilities.

Comment: Since you would have to be running PHP to use `eval()`, it seems a little anti-climactic to point it out, unless you wanted PHP to push the compiled code to the command line, in which case `eval()` I would imagine may be pointless for running PHP code. It would perhaps be more safe to run it in a command line PHP script instead. Although, I suppose I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: @Jared, I think that's probably more secure, and it definitely makes a lot more sense if the server isn't running PHP in the first place. I'm  used to a LAMP environment, so this was the first approach that came to mind.

Comment: @Jared, I've edited your suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of php, an interesting
 thing to do might be:

1. get [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki)
2. compile php interpreter into LLVM bytecode
3. generate javascript from LLVM bytecode
4. run it through the closure compiler for efficiency
5. call the javascript directly from the browser
6. PROFIT

That way, users will not generate any server load (because it's all in the browser) and there will be <strike>no</strike> *fewer* security hazards.

Just thinking aloud

Answer (score 3):

well you need to collect whatever the user types in, save it to a file or pipe to the appropriate compiler. php can [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) anything so as long as you have the tools on your server you'll be good.

Comment: I was also thinking of PHP's `exec()`. Caution, however, needs to be observed. There's also [`system`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [`escapeshellcmd`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)